# C# WPF PrintDialog PrintVisual DataGrid doesnt work for me

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, datagrid

The last 2 Days I already tried to make this work...

So I have a DataGrid in my XAML which I want to print, code following:

```
<TabItem Header="Drucken">
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelPrint" >
        <DataGrid x:Name="DatagridPrint" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Nr}" Header="Nr." Width="40" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Nachname}" Header="Nachname" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Vorname}" Header="Vorname" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Telefon}" Header="Telefon" Width="110"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
```

The StackPanel isnt actually needed, I just tried using it and then printing the StackPanel, but that doesnt work either.

As soon as the User presses the button to print, I have to dynamically add columns to the datagrid and then start the PrintDialog. Code following:

```
private void btnPrintList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new AnzahlEinheiten();
    dialog.Owner = this;
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        int einheiten = Int32.Parse(dialog.Anzahl);
        for (int i = 1; i <= einheiten; i++)
        {
            DatagridPrint.Columns.Add(CreateColumn(i.ToString()));
        }
        DatagridPrint.Columns.Add(CreateColumn("Schn."));

        //printing starts here, above is adding the columns

        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        DatagridPrint.ItemsSource = SelectedKurs.Teilnehmer;
        if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            pd.PrintVisual(DatagridPrint, "Anwesenheitsliste");
        }
    }
}

private DataGridTextColumn CreateColumn(String header)
{
    DataGridTextColumn c = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c.Header = header;
    c.Width = 40;
    return c;
}
```

Setting Landscape works, atleast the PrintDialog shows in the Settings that it already is in Landscape.

Here are now 2 screenshots of the expected Result and my Result.

Expected Result (This is what my DataGrid looks like in WPF after adding the columns) (I just blacked out the names and numbers in paint):

[image: DataGrid Picture]

This is the Result I get when I print in XPS with the Columns Width="*" as above in the Code:

[image: Printed Out 1]

This is the Result I get when I change the Columns Width="150" instead of Width="*":

[image: Printed Out 2]

On the last Screenshot there should be 4 more Columns that are cut off for some reason.

I think the main problem is that it is simply not printing in Landscape while it is set to Landscape. I have no idea how to fix it since I have already searched the last 2 days the whole Internet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think this reference would help you or another.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537126/print-datagrid-records-in-wpf

Comment: I think this reference would help you or another.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537126/print-datagrid-records-in-wpf