# Print all data in the DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing, datagrid

I am working on WPF application. I have data in the DataGrid which I have to print all the data present in it. I tried like this...

```
publicMainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       DataTabledt = newDataTable();
       dt.Columns.Add("S.No");
       dt.Columns.Add("Name");
       dt.Columns.Add("Father's Name");
       dt.Columns.Add("D-O-B");
       dt.Columns.Add("Qualification");
       dt.Columns.Add("Gender");
       dt.Columns.Add("SSC %");
       dt.Columns.Add("+2 %");
       dt.Columns.Add("Graduation %");
       dt.Columns.Add("Work Experience");
       dt.Columns.Add("Company");

       object[] rowValues = {"01","Gopi","Ravi","31","Degree","M", "88","85", "80","2 Years","Blah Blah"};

       dt.Rows.Add(rowValues);
       dt.AcceptChanges();
       myGrid.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
    }

       privatevoidPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       PrintDialogprintDlg = newPrintDialog();
       if ((bool)printDlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
       Sizepagesize = newSize(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth,printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight);
       myGrid.Measure(pagesize);
       myGrid.Arrange(newRect(5, 5, pagesize.Width, pagesize.Height));
            printDlg.PrintVisual(myGrid, "Personal Information");

        }
    }
```

when I click on print button it is printing only the data which we can see as below [image]

But in my case it is not printing work experience and company columns. How can I Print all the fields. Please help me out

EDIT: I think FlowDocument is used, but suppose I have 50 rows I cannot use FlowDocument. How can I Print in this case.

Comment: I would think, the page is simply not wide enough to print all columns. Have you tried to put a viewbox  arround the grid and then print the viewbox?

Comment: @unkreativ It worked. But that is not the case I want, suppose I have 20 Columns of data if I place ViewBox we will get data in small font. Is there any other way.

Answer (score 7):

I have done code recently. It is tested code.It will print every datagrid with all records.It is easy and simple code.You would add a class. If you want to decorate a datagrid then go to PrintDG class then decorate it according to your own requirement.
Follow these steps.
Step1: Add these references on top.

```cs
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Media;

    public  class PrintDG
    {
        public void printDG(DataGrid dataGrid, string title)
        {
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();

                Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Run(title));
                p.FontStyle = dataGrid.FontStyle;
                p.FontFamily = dataGrid.FontFamily;
                p.FontSize = 18;
                fd.Blocks.Add(p);

                Table table = new Table();
                TableRowGroup tableRowGroup = new TableRowGroup();
                TableRow r = new TableRow();
                fd.PageWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
                fd.PageHeight = printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight;
                fd.BringIntoView();

                fd.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                fd.ColumnWidth = 500;
                table.CellSpacing = 0;

                var headerList = dataGrid.Columns.Select(e => e.Header.ToString()).ToList();
                List<dynamic> bindList = new List<dynamic>();

                for (int j = 0; j < headerList.Count; j++)
                {
                    r.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(headerList[j]))));
                    r.Cells[j].ColumnSpan = 4;
                    r.Cells[j].Padding = new Thickness(4);
                    r.Cells[j].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                    r.Cells[j].FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                    r.Cells[j].Background = Brushes.DarkGray;
                    r.Cells[j].Foreground = Brushes.White;
                    r.Cells[j].BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);

                    var binding = (dataGrid.Columns[j] as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding as Binding;
                    bindList.Add(binding.Path.Path);
                }

                tableRowGroup.Rows.Add(r);
                table.RowGroups.Add(tableRowGroup);

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    dynamic row;

                    if (dataGrid.ItemsSource.ToString().ToLower() == "system.data.linqdataview")
                    { row = (DataRowView)dataGrid.Items.GetItemAt(i); }
                    else
                    {
                        row = (BalanceClient)dataGrid.Items.GetItemAt(i);
                    }

                    table.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray;
                    table.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 0, 0);
                    table.FontStyle = dataGrid.FontStyle;
                    table.FontFamily = dataGrid.FontFamily;
                    table.FontSize = 13;
                    tableRowGroup = new TableRowGroup();
                    r = new TableRow();

                    for (int j = 0; j < row.Row.ItemArray.Count(); j++)
                    {
                        if (dataGrid.ItemsSource.ToString().ToLower() == "system.data.linqdataview")
                        {
                            r.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(row.Row.ItemArray[j].ToString()))));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            r.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(row.GetType().GetProperty(bindList[j]).GetValue(row, null)))));
                        }

                        r.Cells[j].ColumnSpan = 4;
                        r.Cells[j].Padding = new Thickness(4);
                        r.Cells[j].BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkGray;
                        r.Cells[j].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 1, 1);
                    }

                    tableRowGroup.Rows.Add(r);
                    table.RowGroups.Add(tableRowGroup);
                }

                fd.Blocks.Add(table);
                printDialog.PrintDocument(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)fd).DocumentPaginator, "");
            }
        }
    }
```

Step2:  Then go to print button click event and create object of PrintDG class then call printDG pass to It two parameters datagridname and title.
Like :

```cs
    private void print_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDG print = new PrintDG();
        print.printDG(datagridName, "Title");
    }
```

If any error occurs during execution tell me and I will solve It.This is running code only, you need copy and paste.
Edited:
I declared row as dynamic. The dynamic keyword decides at run time which type to instantiate, either DataTable or another.

Comment: it throws an `InvalidCastException` at `DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dataGrid.Items.GetItemAt(i);`

Comment: Okey I am changing it.It error occure.Becuase you bind it with list or another typ.

Comment: `bindList` is not declared.

Comment: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''myType' does not contain a definition for 'Row''

Comment: i'm still getting the same error when trying to cast my data. i don't know what type `BalanceClient` is so i remove it and i'm getting an error that my data does not contain a definition for 'Row'

Comment: you should put your class name.which class you bind data.

Comment: I will adjust it according to every class data.

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi thank you for the code, I made some adjustments and it works well. Do you know how to only print the cells that are visible on the DataGrid? I have more cells in the itemssource that I do not display to the user.

Comment: hi @MuhammadMehdi what is this BalanceClient?

Answer (score 1):

I work with This :

```
  // Author : Kadi Okba
public class WpfPrinting
{
    public const double cm = 37;
    public double Margin = 0.5 * cm;
    public double PageWidth = 21 * cm;
    public double PageHeight = 29 * cm;
    public double RowHeight = 0.7 * cm;
    public bool PageNumberVisibility = true;
    public bool DateVisibility = true;
    public double FontSize = 14;
    public double HeaderFontSize = 14;
    public bool IsBold = false;
    public void PrintDataGrid(FrameworkElement header, DataGrid grid, FrameworkElement footer, PrintDialog printDialog)
    {
        if (header == null) { header = new FrameworkElement(); header.Width = 1; header.Height = 1; }
        if (footer == null) { footer = new FrameworkElement(); footer.Width = 1; footer.Height = 1; }
        if (grid == null) return;

        Size pageSize = new Size(PageWidth, PageHeight);

        FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = pageSize;

        double GridActualWidth = grid.ActualWidth == 0 ? grid.Width : grid.ActualWidth;

        double PageWidthWithMargin = pageSize.Width - Margin * 2;
        double PageHeightWithMargin = pageSize.Height - Margin * 2;



        // scale the header  
        double headerScale = (header?.Width ?? 0) / PageWidthWithMargin;
        double headerWidth = PageWidthWithMargin;
        double headerHeight = (header?.Height ?? 0) * headerScale;
        header.Height = headerHeight;
        header.Width = headerWidth;
        // scale the footer  
        double footerScale = (footer?.Width ?? 0) / PageWidthWithMargin;
        double footerWidth = PageWidthWithMargin;
        double footerHeight = (footer?.Height ?? 0) * footerScale;
        footer.Height = footerHeight;
        footer.Width = footerWidth;

        int pageNumber = 1;
        string Now = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

        //add the header 
        FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
        fixedPage.Background = Brushes.White;
        fixedPage.Width = pageSize.Width;
        fixedPage.Height = pageSize.Height;

        FixedPage.SetTop(header, Margin);
        FixedPage.SetLeft(header, Margin);

        fixedPage.Children.Add(header);
        // its like cursor for current page Height to start add grid rows
        double CurrentPageHeight = headerHeight + 1 * cm;
        int lastRowIndex = 0;
        bool IsFooterAdded = false;

        for (;;)
        {
            int AvaliableRowNumber;


            var SpaceNeededForRestRows = (CurrentPageHeight + (grid.Items.Count - lastRowIndex) * RowHeight);

            //To avoid printing the footer in a separate page
            if (SpaceNeededForRestRows > (pageSize.Height - footerHeight - Margin) && (SpaceNeededForRestRows < (pageSize.Height - Margin)))
                AvaliableRowNumber = (int)((pageSize.Height - CurrentPageHeight - Margin - footerHeight) / RowHeight);
            // calc the Avaliable Row acording to CurrentPageHeight
            else AvaliableRowNumber = (int)((pageSize.Height - CurrentPageHeight - Margin) / RowHeight);

            // create new page except first page cause we created it prev
            if (pageNumber > 1)
            {
                fixedPage = new FixedPage();
                fixedPage.Background = Brushes.White;
                fixedPage.Width = pageSize.Width;
                fixedPage.Height = pageSize.Height;
            }

            // create new data grid with  columns width and binding
            DataGrid gridToAdd;
            gridToAdd = GetDataGrid(grid, GridActualWidth, PageWidthWithMargin);


            FixedPage.SetTop(gridToAdd, CurrentPageHeight); // top margin
            FixedPage.SetLeft(gridToAdd, Margin); // left margin

            // add the avaliable rows to the cuurent grid 
            for (int i = lastRowIndex; i < grid.Items.Count && i < AvaliableRowNumber + lastRowIndex; i++)
            {
                gridToAdd.Items.Add(grid.Items[i]);
            }
            lastRowIndex += gridToAdd.Items.Count + 1;

            // add date
            TextBlock dateText = new TextBlock();
            if (DateVisibility) dateText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            else dateText.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            dateText.Text = Now;

            // add page number
            TextBlock PageNumberText = new TextBlock();
            if (PageNumberVisibility) PageNumberText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            else PageNumberText.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            PageNumberText.Text = "Page : " + pageNumber;

            FixedPage.SetTop(dateText, PageHeightWithMargin);
            FixedPage.SetLeft(dateText, Margin);

            FixedPage.SetTop(PageNumberText, PageHeightWithMargin);
            FixedPage.SetLeft(PageNumberText, PageWidthWithMargin - PageNumberText.Text.Length * 10);

            fixedPage.Children.Add(gridToAdd);
            fixedPage.Children.Add(dateText);
            fixedPage.Children.Add(PageNumberText);

            // calc Current Page Height to know the rest Height of this page
            CurrentPageHeight += gridToAdd.Items.Count * RowHeight;

            // all grid rows added
            if (lastRowIndex >= grid.Items.Count)
            {
                // if footer have space it will be added to the same page
                if (footerHeight < (PageHeightWithMargin - CurrentPageHeight))
                {
                    FixedPage.SetTop(footer, CurrentPageHeight + Margin);
                    FixedPage.SetLeft(footer, Margin);

                    fixedPage.Children.Add(footer);
                    IsFooterAdded = true;
                }
            }

            fixedPage.Measure(pageSize);
            fixedPage.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), pageSize));
            fixedPage.UpdateLayout();

            PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
            ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
            fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);

            pageNumber++;
            // go to start position : New page Top
            CurrentPageHeight = Margin;

            // this mean that lastRowIndex >= grid.Items.Count  and the footer dont have enough space
            if (lastRowIndex >= grid.Items.Count && !IsFooterAdded)
            {
                FixedPage ffixedPage = new FixedPage();
                ffixedPage.Background = Brushes.White;
                ffixedPage.Width = pageSize.Width;
                ffixedPage.Height = pageSize.Height;

                FixedPage.SetTop(footer, Margin);
                FixedPage.SetLeft(footer, Margin);

                TextBlock fdateText = new TextBlock();
                if (DateVisibility) fdateText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                else fdateText.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                dateText.Text = Now;

                TextBlock fPageNumberText = new TextBlock();
                if (PageNumberVisibility) fPageNumberText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                else fPageNumberText.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                fPageNumberText.Text = "Page : " + pageNumber;

                FixedPage.SetTop(fdateText, PageHeightWithMargin);
                FixedPage.SetLeft(fdateText, Margin);

                FixedPage.SetTop(fPageNumberText, PageHeightWithMargin);
                FixedPage.SetLeft(fPageNumberText, PageWidthWithMargin - PageNumberText.ActualWidth);

                ffixedPage.Children.Add(footer);
                ffixedPage.Children.Add(fdateText);
                ffixedPage.Children.Add(fPageNumberText);

                ffixedPage.Measure(pageSize);
                ffixedPage.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), pageSize));
                ffixedPage.UpdateLayout();

                PageContent fpageContent = new PageContent();
                ((IAddChild)fpageContent).AddChild(ffixedPage);
                fixedDoc.Pages.Add(fpageContent);
                IsFooterAdded = true;
            }

            if (IsFooterAdded)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        PrintFixedDocument(fixedDoc, printDialog);
    }
    private DataGrid GetDataGrid(DataGrid grid, double GridActualWidth, double PageWidthWithMargin)
    {
        DataGrid printed = new DataGrid();


        // styling the grid
        Style rowStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
        rowStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.White));
        rowStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontSizeProperty, FontSize));
        if (IsBold) rowStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold));
        rowStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.HeightProperty, RowHeight));


        Style columnStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontSizeProperty, HeaderFontSize));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0, 0.5, 0, 1.5)));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.White));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Black));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.SemiBold));


        printed.RowStyle = rowStyle;

        printed.VerticalGridLinesBrush = Brushes.Black;
        printed.HorizontalGridLinesBrush = Brushes.Black;
        printed.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");

        printed.RowBackground = Brushes.White;
        printed.Background = Brushes.White;
        printed.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        // get the columns of grid 
        foreach (var column in grid.Columns)
        {
            if (column.Visibility != Visibility.Visible) continue;
            DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
            textColumn.HeaderStyle = columnStyle;
            textColumn.Header = column.Header;
            textColumn.Width = column.ActualWidth / GridActualWidth * PageWidthWithMargin;
            textColumn.Binding = ((DataGridTextColumn)column).Binding;
            printed.Columns.Add(textColumn);
        }
        printed.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;


        return printed;
    }

    public void PrintFixedDocument(FixedDocument fixedDoc, PrintDialog printDialog)
    {
        XpsDocumentWriter writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printDialog.PrintQueue);
        writer.Write(fixedDoc, printDialog.PrintTicket);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use it ? , any usage Example !