# WPF Printing DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have a `DataGrid` with Content and some other Backgrounds in some cells.
Now I want to print it. I tried it with the `PrintDialog` to print the whole `DataGrid` but it only prints with the width of my DataGrid, if I resize it, it won't print on the whole paper.

Is there a way to specify some Templates, the Printer should use and fill the template with the Content of my `DataGrid` or what is the best way to print the Content of a `DataGrid`?

Comment: generate crystal reports and then from there you can print as you wish

Comment: @sibysunny is Crystal Reports free?

Comment: take a look on this. This is free http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/013102/how-to-create-report-rdlc-in-wpf/

Comment: @sibysunny yes, but I ment the API. Is it free to download?

Comment: You can print all the rows of your datagrid using Check This:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42596327/5587426