# Print visible rows in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698316/print-all-data-in-the-datagrid-in-wpf/50281632#50281632) to print my datagrids. The only problem is the DataTable I use as the ItemsSource for my DataGrid has more columns than I am displaying in the datagrid, which are being added to the print out too.

How can I only add the values that are visible to the flowdocument?

```
                for (int j = 0; j < row.Row.ItemArray.Length; j++)
                {
                    r.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(row.Row.ItemArray[j].ToString()))));

                    r.Cells.Last().ColumnSpan = 4;
                    r.Cells.Last().Padding = new Thickness(4);

                    r.Cells.Last().BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkGray;
                    r.Cells.Last().BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 1, 1);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

When picking the columns from the data grid, filter them by visibility

```
var headerList = dataGrid.Columns.Where(x=>x.Visibility == Visibility.Visible).Select(e => e.Header.ToString()).ToList();
```