# Print DataGrid WPF if use connection string

Tags: c, wpf, datagrid

I have one question. How can I print all the records in the Datagrid.
I am using normal code for printing.

```
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
printDlg.PrintVisual(grid1, "Grid Printing.");
```

But it prints out the window itself. It's not beautiful. How do I print only records?

Please note that I am using DB connection string in WPF.

I want the output to be something like this, thanks!

P.s.
I can't attach a picture, so I'll attach a link to the guy's video, look at the document at the end of the video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhsGGLREqu8&ab_channel=CsharpSpace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print all data in the DataGrid in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698316/print-all-data-in-the-datagrid-in-wpf)

Comment: @Rekshino
I looked, but I did not understand what it means in the code BalanceClient? He said something about the class, but I didn't understand anything. I am Russian, I do not understand English well.

Comment: See comments. Otherwise try to post to the local resource [SO.ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).