# How do i print all columns and rows from a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, printdialog

I have a wpf application.  Upon a user request I create a datagrid of certain columns for all the data from a database.  I need to print this information.  Preferably I would like to print all odd pages first and then all even pages with a header and footer.  I have the following code so far but when I print I only get what I see on the screen.  I am sure it is `pdPrintDialog.PrintVisual` statement.  I am assuming I need to use `pdPrintDialog.PrintDocument`.  But I don't know to convert the datagrid or `datagrid.itemssource` to `Documents.DocumentPaginator`.  I can not find how to do this anywhere.  Please help!

```
System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog pdPrintDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

 if ((bool)pdPrintDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
 {
     Size pntPageSize = new Size(pdPrintDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, pdPrintDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);
     dgPWLCGrid.Measure(pntPageSize);
     dgPWLCGrid.Arrange(new Rect(5, 5, pntPageSize.Width, pntPageSize.Height));
     pdPrintDialog.PrintVisual(dgPWLCGrid, "North Berwick Food Pantry Client Info");
 }
```

Comment: Possibly this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537126/print-datagrid-records-in-wpf

Comment: #Dazzler - I am already using the c# code.  How does the xaml code help the c# code to print the whole data in the datagrid?  Is it the binding process?  I don't see code to show how itemssource = "{Binding}" works.

Comment: Can anyone please give me an example or answer my question to #Dazzler?